# Privacy keys added but still crash on dismiss UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession, gpuimage

Going Crazy。

Using *UIImagePickerController* to take picture,
After presenting the pickerController, cosole prints 
**[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles** and **[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.**

App crashes after dismiss pickerController for 1-2 seconds.
and the console says **-[AVCaptureSession release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1c4201080**

Privacy keys already added:
[image]

and the related code sample:

```
 func seletedImage()  {

    let alertAction = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertAction.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "拍照", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] (alertCamera) in
        self?.showImagePicker(sourceType: .camera)
    }))
    alertAction.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "从相册中选择", style:.default, handler: { [weak self] (alertPhpto) in
        self?.showImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }))
    alertAction.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "取消", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alertAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

 func showImagePicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) == false {
        if sourceType == .camera { print("未授予使用相机权限") }
        if sourceType == .photoLibrary { print("未授予访问相册权限") }
        return
    }

    let picker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    picker.sourceType = sourceType
    picker.allowsEditing = false

    weak var weakself = self
    weakself?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

am I missing some other important configurations?
maybe something related to *GPUImage*?

any help is really really appreciate.

PS. it crashes even I don't take a picture and just cancel directly. the *photoLibrary* type works fine.

Comment: The crash has nothing to do with the privacy keys in Info.plist.

Comment: Why are you casting `self` as `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate`? Your class should properly conform to those protocols then the cast won't be necessary.

Comment: @rmaddy simply changed to picker.delegate = self, the problem still exist. what directions should i try to locate the problem? and as presenting the imagePicker, console print : [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles  and  [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

Comment: it turned out to be something related to KVO/runtime in my case, other guy imported this [DSKVO](https://github.com/bigsen/DSKVO) framework, which cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please handle a case that camera is not available . Please use below code

```
func  SelectFromCamera()  {

    //Camera
    let cameraMediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: cameraMediaType) { granted in
        if granted {
            print("Granted access to \(cameraMediaType)")
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType =
                    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
                //  imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true,
                             completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            //open app setting if not authorize to access camera
            print("Denied access to \(cameraMediaType)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi dude, I have checked the availability as 'if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) == false {
            return
        }'